# Python file opens in python2.7 instead of python3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I'm writing a game for a school project. My game works, as long as you run it from IDLE 3.4. I've tried adding `#!python3` to the top of the file, but to no avail. Secondarily, it only opens pictures if I run from IDLE, and says something about PIL not being installed in PATH, which is running python27

EDIT: attempting to double-click open, running on Windows. Found the shebang line somewhere and tried it.

MORE EDIT: ended up just writing a batch file that would open the python file with python3.

Ended up doing this:

```
@echo off
py -3 filename.py
```

Comment: what do you mean 2 instead of 3 do you mean the version of python ? I assume you are running under linux by the use of the shebang line.... more information please :)

Comment: How are you attempting to launch it?

Comment: sorry about lack of info. I'm running it from Windows 7, and 2 and 3 refer to versions of python

Answer (score 0):

open start menu -> all programs -> python 3.x -> IDLE(Python ...) after that click file then go to open or just do `ctrl + o`, find the file you want to run  and it should open it using python 3.

Comment: That works but I want it to open in python3 on doubleclick from explorer

Comment: Ok, left click the file and then click open with -> click browse -> go to your python 3 folder and click the file called python in the python 3 folfde

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..., shebang is only interpreted by Unix-like shells, so it is useless on Windows! On Windows you can define the default program to be used per file extension.

From the symptoms, I assume that you have both Python2 and Python3 installed, and that `*.py` files are currently associated with Python2.

You can associated them with Python3 that way:

- open control panel, click or tap Programs, and then Default Programs. You can then change the program associated to `*.py` to Python3 (and/or `*.pyw` to Python3w)
- alternatively, you can right click the file on window explorer and choose `Open with...` you will be allowed to choose the program to be used *that time* with the option to record the choice for all programs with same extension